# selecting row of data based on different column of data using python

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, bioinformatics, data-analysis

i am trying to filter the data from a .csv file where there are different columns, as shown below-:

[image]

and the desired result shown is according to the annotation column should contain "human" or homosapians" the the list shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get groups if match conditions by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then again filter original DataFrame:

```
df =df[df['extId'].isin(df.loc[df['Annotation'].isin(['human','homosapians']), 'extId'])]
```

Or test if at least one value match in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df =df[df['Annotation'].isin(['human','homosapians']).groupby(df['extId']).transform('any')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[(df['Annotation'] == 'human') | (df['Annotation'] == 'homosapians')]
```